# How can I create a class diagram from my J2ME project? (NetBeans used to do this)

Tags: java-me, uml, class-diagram

I have created a game and would like to automatically create a class diagram from my J2ME code. NetBeans (pre 6.5 I think) used to have UML plugin to do this, but as I am using the latest 6.8 version of NetBeans I can't use this old UML plugin anymore!

Does anyone know how I can automatically create a class diagram from my J2ME project?

Comment: I don't understand, what's the use of doing a class diagram on something you created, after creating it ? UML is used to design your app.

Comment: I know it has no use, But try telling my tutor this! We have created a basic class diagram as part of the design process but he wants us to show if (and if so, how?) the application differs from our designed class diagram.  

It's education, so its a case of dont argue just do as your told. i.e jump through the hoop and dance like a monkey!

Comment: Anyway UML diagrams are usefull after creating live classes for refactoring purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I try to find any free reverse engineering uml tool and find nothing good except netbeans uml editor.
EclipseUML Omondo Free Edition is quite good, but on free edition do not support reverse engineering As far as I know. But if you need a one time diagram - you can try trial EclipseUML Omondo Studio Edition. But in this case you need port project to eclipse - not so hard as it looks. Good luck!

Comment: well in that case do you think it might be worth installing an old version of netbeans that the uml plugin will work with?    

If I cant find a better solution I think I'll use the latest 6.8 version for coding and an old pre 6.5 version just for uml diagrams.

Also as I am on a linux machine I have been looking at umbrello. does anyone have any experience of this app?

Comment: Yes, installing old version pretty the same as installign eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

umbrello seems to do the job! [link text](http://uml.sourceforge.net/)

Although I do have to manually drag and drop classes to get them to display! but thats better than making the whole thing manually I suppose!